# BaseExpandableListAdapter notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't regenerate the adapter

Tags: android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a problem with the method notifyDataSetChange() which is called inside the a method onClickListener from a ImageView. When I click on the image, the adapter must regenerate the view getting from a List which are stored the views. Here is some code:

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Product currentProduct = parentList.get(groupPosition).getProduct();
    convertView = parentList.get(groupPosition).getParentView();
if(type == TicketType.FRAGMENTED){
        productHeaderCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
productHeaderCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (parentList.get(groupPosition).isChecked()){
                    parentList.get(groupPosition).setChecked(false);
                    parentList.get(groupPosition).uncheckAllChildrenItems();
                    TicketFragment.updateTicketPrice(currentAmount,false);
                }else{
                    TicketFragment.updateTicketPrice(getCurrentAmount(parentList.get(groupPosition), currentAmount), true);
                    parentList.get(groupPosition).setChecked(true);
                    parentList.get(groupPosition).checkAllChildrenItems();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your parentList list static? could you have multiple instances? are you using a singleton model

Comment: @MarkGilchrist My parentList is not static and I don't have multiple instances. On the other hand, a singleton model is defined for my project. Thanks!!